# Running Postgres stored procedure with C#

Tags: c#, postgresql, stored-procedures, entity-framework-core

I created a stored procedure `stocks.public.daily_actions_full()` that not receive or return something, it just inserts data from a view to a table.

After using using `dbcontext scaffold` all the tables and views were added except the stored procedures.

I saw that it's a known issue and the option to call stored procedures is to use `ExecuteSqlCommand`.

I tried the following code:

```
using (var db = new stocksContext())
{
    var rowsAffected = db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("CALL stocks.public.daily_actions_full()");
}
```

But I'm getting the following error:

[image: error]

Not sure what I'm missing here or if there's another way to call stored procedures.

Maybe adding it to the context file manually? (Couldn't find how)

Thanks!

Comment: `ExecuteSqlCommand` was removed from EF core after 3.1.  There is `ExecuteSqlCommandAsync`

Comment: I'm still getting the error I mentioned above. `'DatabaseFacade' does not contain a definition for 'ExecuteSqlCommandAsync' and no accessible extension method 'ExecuteSqlCommandAsync' accepting a first argument of type 'DatabaseFacade' could be found`

Comment: Do you have `using System.Data.Entity;` at the top of the file?

Comment: There is no `ExecuteSqlCommand` method in the [DatabaseFacade](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.infrastructure.databasefacade?view=efcore-5.0) class. There are `ExecuteSqlRaw` and `ExecuteSqlInterpolated` methods (and their asynchronous versions).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Alexander Petrov wrote here:
**Use ExecuteSqlRaw to solve it.**
Thanks everyone for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have installed package Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL and Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer

There is no overload ExecuteSqlCommand without any parameters. So try this

```
 var rowsAffected = db.Database
.ExecuteSqlCommand("Call stocks.public.daily_actions_full()", null);
```

UPDATE

You can try to use ExecuteSqlRaw but in this case you will need much more code

Create model for return result

```
public class SpResult
{
 public int RowsAffected {get; set;}
}
```

Then add this model to the dbcontext

```
  public virtual DbSet<SpResult> SpResults { get; set; }

   //and OnModelCreating

   modelBuilder.Entity<SpResult>(e =>
            {
                e.HasNoKey();
            });
```

Only after this you can get your result from SP

```
public string GetApproverCode(int ReqId)
    {
       var rowsAffectedObj = db.SpResults.ExecuteSqlRaw("Call stocks.public.daily_actions_full()", null)
              .ToList()
             .FirstOrDefault();
   
  var rowsAffected=0; 

 if(rowsAffectedObj !=null) rowsAffected= rowsAffectedObj.RowsAffected;
```

Comment: I'm still getting the error I mentioned above.
`'DatabaseFacade' does not contain a definition for 'ExecuteSqlCommand' and no accessible extension method 'ExecuteSqlCommand' accepting a first argument of type 'DatabaseFacade' could be found`

Comment: Can you post your startup pls?  What kind of  dbcontext are you using?

Comment: isnt the command type required and not the "exec" part

Comment: Yes, you certainaly need it  to execute a strored procedure. Exec or execute

Comment: Sorry it is fo MS Sql Server . But for Postgresql is used Call

Comment: There is no `ExecuteSqlCommand` method in the [DatabaseFacade](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.infrastructure.databasefacade?view=efcore-5.0) class. There are `ExecuteSqlRaw` and `ExecuteSqlInterpolated` methods (and their asynchronous versions).

Comment: @Serge, thx for your help, and sorry for my delay.
I followed your instructions and I received the following error:
`'DbSet<SpResult>' does not contain a definition for 'ExecuteSqlRaw' and the best extension method overload 'RelationalDatabaseFacadeExtensions.ExecuteSqlRaw(DatabaseFacade, string, params object[])' requires a receiver of type 'DatabaseFacade'`

Comment: Have you installed Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer ?

Comment: And try to add using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure;